# How to turn off default image listing of jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I have downloaded a nice jQuery file uploader with progress bar from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

and after little bit customization I have uploaded into my server.

```
http://209.217.224.101/~team/file_upload/admin/parent_window.php
```

Click "Open Child Window". you get here all images which are already uploaded into this path. and you can upload new images. everything is working fine. 
BUT I need not to load those images. "Open child window" will not load any images of that directory.

You can download full package of me from

```
http://209.217.224.101/~team/file_upload/file_upload.rar
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes i have solved it in alternate ways. using a js variable in current script which is set to value 0. every time when image will upload it will increase by 1. in last block i have changed the line

```
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
```

to

```
{% if(list_img>0) for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
```

and at bottom of template-uplaod script i have added

```
{% list_img=list_img+1; %}
```